# Can I run power from a GFCI receptacle to a standard receptacle then to a light switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I have a single GFCI outlet and I want to add a few standard receptacles and a light from it.  I am curious if it is possible to go from the GFCI, to two standard outlets then on to a light switch?

Comment: I would be disinclined to put a light on a GFCI circuit with outlets. If your GFCI trips, you're in the dark! I'd run separate wires for the light, tapping off of the LINE side of the GFCI.

Comment: Having your lights on a separate circuit seems to have many advantages.

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes.  GFCI outlets have LINE and LOAD terminals.

You can connect several more outlets on the LOAD terminals, and they will also be protected from ground faults.

You can also add a switch, though bear in mind that highly inductive loads (like a large motor) can cause nuisance tripping of the GFCI.

Comment: The gfci ends in the unfinished part of the basement and I want to run from this to a small finished office in the finished side of the basement if permissible. I am located in Maine. So I would go from the load side of the gfci to the standard receptacles and then wire to the light switch as normal?

Comment: @user35431 -- since it's a basement circuit, yes, that sounds right.

Comment: At least where I am, basement circuits have to be run in conduit or above fireproof ceilings.  I've got several outlets daisychained off of GFCI outlets.  Just make sure that the light isn't wired in series with the GFCIs.

Comment: a very long circuit (more than 100 feet usually) can cause GFCI problems

Answer (score 1):

Sure, within limits - it may depend where the GFCI is and where in the world you are - if the prevailing electrical code requires a circuit dedicated to one room, and you extend it beyond that room, you would be violating code.

Other than THAT, yes, it's certainly possible - connect from the LOAD terminals on the GFCI to the first outlet, from the first outlet to the second, and from the second to the switch and the opposite side of the switched item.